# Why is the Vodapay test app not allowing me to reset my PIN?

Tags: vodapay-miniprogram

I used the wrong PIN on my account multiple times on the super-app, now its refusing to allow me to reset it. How do I proceed from here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a security measure, the account will be blocked for 24hrs and then automatically unblocked. Please avoid continuing to try logging in on that account as you can then be blocked for 7 days. For now, I would suggest that you create a new account and continue with your development work.